# create threaded class functions with arguments inside class

Tags: multithreading, c++11, stdthread

I have an object of class `AI`, which has a private non static void function which has a lot of arguments: `minmax(double& val,double alpha, double beta, unsigned short depth, board* thisTurn)`; because this is a very time intensive function I want to use a number of threads to run it concurrently, therefor I must create a thread with this function inside another function inside the AI class;

According to[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17472827/create-thread-inside-class-with-function-from-same-class#17472910) to make threads inside member functions containing non static member functions wiht no arguments of said class, one must call:

```
std::thread t(&myclass::myfunc,this);
```

And according to [this tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/540912/cplusplus-threads-make-your-multitasking-life-e) threads of fucntions with multiple arguments can be created as such:

```
std::thread t(foo,4,5)
```

where the function 'foo' has 2 integer arguments

However I desire to mix these to things, to call a function which has arguments, which is also a non static member function, from inside the class that it is a member of, and i am not sure how to mix these to things.

I have off course tried (remember that it is inside a function inside the AI class):

```
std::thread t(&AI::minmax,val,alpha,beta,depth,thisTurn,this);
```

and

```
std::thread t(&AI::minmax,this,val,alpha,beta,depth,thisTurn);
```

But both cases fails with a compile error like this:

```
error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'std::thread'
candidate constructor template not viable: requires single argument '__f', but
  7 arguments were provided
```

My question is therefor, if or if not, it is even possiple to -- from inside a member function of a class -- call a non static member function which has several arguments as a thread, and if this is the case, how it is done.

This question is however not wether or not it is a good idea to use multithreading in my specific case.

## Edit

After doing some testing i realized that i can not call functions with arguments as threads at all, not even non-member functions with only one argument called directly from main, this was however solved by asking [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42225389/calling-threaded-functions-with-arguments-not-possiple) where i realized that i simply need to add the flag -std=c++11 (because apparantly macs don't always use all c++11 features as standard) after doing so the answer works fine.

Comment: try `std::thread t(&AI::minmax,this,std::ref(val),alpha,beta,depth,thisTurn,this);`

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki doing so gives the same error as before, and this new error `no matching function for call to '__invoke'`

Comment: show the code or it never happened

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki You have one "this" too much. It should read `std::thread t(&AI::minmax, this, std::ref(val), alpha, beta, depth, thisTurn);`.

Comment: @pschill a copy-paste of OP's code but probably you're right

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki The OP did not use `std::ref`.

Comment: @pschill geez, *copy-paste-fix-overlook-op's-mistake*, fine now ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap references using `std::ref`. The following example compiles fine:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

class board;

class AI
{
public:

    void minmax(double& val, double alpha, double beta, unsigned short depth, board* thisTurn)
    {
        std::cout << "minmax" << std::endl;
    }

    void spawnThread()
    {
        double val;
        double alpha;
        double beta;
        unsigned short depth;
        board* thisTurn;

        std::thread t(&AI::minmax, this, std::ref(val), alpha, beta, depth, thisTurn);

        t.join();
    }

};

int main()
{
    AI ai;
    ai.spawnThread();
}
```

Comment: that example code still produces two error: firstly: std::ref cause compiler error: `error: no matching function for call to '__invoke'`followed by several lines of: `...in file included from...` but in the end indicating that the problem is `std::ref(val)`. Secondly it cause the old `no matching constructor for initialization of 'std::thread' candidate constructor template not viable: requires single argument '__f', but
      7 arguments were provided`

Comment: @Nikolaj The code I posted compiles well in Visual Studio 2015 (see http://rextester.com/ALGB12143). I do not have VS2013 here to test the code, and earlier versions will not work because `#include <thread>` is missing there. What compiler do you use?